# I'm requesting help fixing sqlite syntax to retrive data from a table

Tags: python, sqlite

The problem.

I'm trying to retrieve data from a SQLite3 database using Python
The code is below. (I've cut out any unneccesary parts).

````
date = input("Please enter date shown on the retrieved data exactly as it is written, Including brackets and commas: ")
U_P = int(input("Please enter the number that was imediately after the date shown: "))
j = 1
for j in range(j , U_P + 1):
    str_U_P = str(U_P)
    str_date = str(date)
    O_ID = (str_date, j, '/', str_U_P, U_ID)
    str_O_ID = str(O_ID)
    print(str_O_ID)
    cursor.execute("select * from NEA_Orders where O_ID = '%s'" %str_O_ID)
    Data = str(cursor.fetchall())
    Data = Data.strip (" (),' ")
    print(Data)```
````

An example of the data shown before this is **[(59, "('(9, 2, 2021)', '2', 'Test3')")]**.
I'm trying to get the above code to retrieve data from a SQL database.
The error is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "U:\.A_Level Files\A-level Computor Science\Y12-13\NEA\NEA_Module.py", line 228, in View_data
    cursor.execute("select * from NEA_Orders where O_ID = '%s'" %str_O_ID)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

The output data for the part of the code that works is **('(9, 2, 2021)', 1, '/', '2', 'Test3')**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use literal parameter values when the value may contain `'` characters

Use instead bound parameters :

```
cursor.execute("select * from NEA_Orders where O_ID = ?", (str_O_ID, ))
```

It is also much more secure, as it prevents SQL injections